# <FilesMatch> in apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, download

I am using apache 2.4 and I want to create a link on my website to download a picture.

According to what I have found on Google, I have to put the following lines :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

But I dont know in which file I have to put this, because what I have found is about `.htaccess` and `httpd.conf` files, but those dont exist on Apache 2.4.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Create a new `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file and put this code there.

**Option 2:** Otherwise place this code in your Apache config and restart your Apache server

Comment: I have edited my apach config and restarted with success.
But it does not work, I have a link like this : `<a href="../data/1.jpg">here</a>`, but when I click on it, the picture is displayed in a new tab...

Comment: Can you try this in `.htaccess` I don't know what `Header set Content-Disposition attachment` actually does.

Comment: I have found my mistake, I have added a `download` attibute in my html and it works fine. Thank for your help.